# Applying Fixed to Inner Div Disables Overflow:Hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div inside another div. The outer div has a starting width & height of 0px & slowly increases in width & height, which creates the effect of slowly revealing the inner div(from the centre outwards).

I do this using Javascripts setInterval & just increase the dimensions of the outer div every iteration.

Because the outer div is **absolutely positioned** I find that I need to recentre(horiz & vert) the inner div within the outer div to **ensure that I reveal the div from the exact centre outwards** as the outer div expands.

**Is there an automatic way to ensure that the inner div is always centred within the outer div as it expands? Using CSS or any other method?**

The best way I have found is if I change the inner divs position to **fixed** but then the overflow:hidden(on the outer div) doesnt get adherred to???

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Using Javascript I will slowly increase the outer divs width & height: making the innerdiv slowly appear. 
         Although, as the outer div resizes, the inner div will be positioned relativly, how can I keep its position at 20,20 of the body ALL the time? -->
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: blue; left: 10px; top: 10px; width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="position: fixed; background-color: red; left: 20px; top: 20px; width: 500px; height: 300px;">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need IE7 support, I'd suggest you use display:table-cell to achieve the vertical centering.

http://jsfiddle.net/fte2t/1/

If you do need IE7, only way will be by use of table, i'm afraid...